# ¿Cómo cuento el número de caracteres que tiene un fichero línea a línea, incluyendo saltos de línea?

Tags: python

tengo que hacer un programa que cuenta los elementos de una cadena, incluido los saltos de linea de un archivo de texto, mi duda es que no consigue el código que he realizado contabilizar los saltos de linea.

```
fichero = open('texto5_8.txt', 'r')
caracteres=0
for linea in fichero:
  caracteres+=len(linea)
  if linea=='\n':
      caracteres+=1
print caracteres
```

Sólo cuenta los 303 caracteres del texto pero no los 6 elementos más que corresponden a los saltos de linea. Gracias de antemano

El texto es el siguiente

```
Unas horas despues de que Donald Trump y Joe 
Biden se enfrentaran en Cleveland en un tosco 
primer debate lleno de gritos y descalificaciones 
personales, al otro lado del Pacifico dos mujeres 
mas jovenes protagonizaron otro debate presidencial mucho 
mas afable y civilizado que el de Estados Unidos
```

Comment: nótese que también puedes hacer `with open(fichero, 'r') as f:` y luego seguir con `for line in f`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Cuando iteras por un fichero con una construcción como `for linea in fichero:` la variable `linea` contiene una línea completa *incluyendo el carácter nueva-linea*.

Es decir, en tu caso, la primera iteración dejará en `linea` la cadena `'Unas horas despues de que Donald Trump y Joe\n'`

Ya que esa cadena *ya contiene* el carácter `\n` no necesitas contarlo de forma especial. Simplemente `len(linea)` te dará el número de caracteres en esa línea y el `\n` contará como un carácter más. Por tanto un bucle como el siguiente te dará todos los caracteres, incluídos los `\n`:

```
fichero = open('texto5_8.txt', 'r')
caracteres=0
for linea in fichero:
  caracteres+=len(linea)
```

Tu condición `if linea=='\n'` no es necesaria, aunque de todas formas tampoco se va a cumplir ya que ninguna línea se compone únicamente del carácter `\n` (a menos que tu fichero contenga líneas en blanco, pero incluso en ese caso serían contadas correctamente con el bucle anterior)

### Observación

Sin embargo dices que el resultado no es el que esperabas. Esperabas por alguna razón 6 más. ¿Por qué? Se me ocurre la siguiente posible explicación. Has mirado el tamaño del archivo y has encontrado que en vez de 303 es de 309. ¿Es eso?

Si este es el caso puede deberse a que el fichero ha sido creado en un sistema Windows que añade al final de cada línea **dos caracteres** en vez de uno (`\r\n` en vez de `\n`). Si este es el caso, efectivamente los `\r` no estarían siendo contados, porque al abrir el fichero en modo texto python automáticamente traduce cada pareja `\r\n` a un solo `\n`. Las líneas que ve tu programa ya no contienen el `\r`.

Para este caso deberás abrir el fichero en modo binario en vez de modo texto, mediante `open("fichero", "rb")`. De ese modo sí recibirás ya todos los bytes, incluyendo los `\r` y tendrás la cuenta que esperas.

No obstante este segundo método estaría contando *bytes* en vez de *caracteres*. Si el texto contiene solo ASCII serían lo mismo, pero si contiene caracteres no-ASCII dependerá de la codificación usada. En UTF-8 un carácter puede ocupar varios bytes.

### Nota adicional

También puedes contar todos los caracteres (o bytes si abres en modo binario) simplemente leyendo el fichero completo en vez de línea a línea, y luego midiendo la longitud de la cadena recibida. Es decir:

```
fichero = open('texto5_8.txt', 'r')
texto_completo = fichero.read()
caracteres = len(texto_completo)
```

Comment: Supongo que buscaba algo así como `if linea.endswith('\n'): c += 1`, pero efectivamente no hace falta.

Comment: Dependiendo del editor usado, sus opciones y el S.O., la línea puede estar terminada con dos caracteres: \r\n.

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas leer el archivo para calcular el número de caracter; puedes simplemente preguntar por el tamaño del archivo:

```
print(os.path.getsize("texto5_8.txt"))
```

Nota: aplican las observaciones de la respuesta de @abulafia.